# How to hide keyboard and button simultaneously when click back button of device/phone

Tags: android, back-button, keyevent

How to hide keyboard and button when clicking the back button of device/phone?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

call on the onBackPressed() of Activity

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 super.onBackPressed();
 public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputMethodManager.isActive()) {
            if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: also how to hide button simultaneously when click back button of device/phone? :((

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation check this link

Answer (score 1):

Below is `onKeyDown` method is call when you pressed back `button`:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed(); \\Method call hear
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Now call the hide keyboard function in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    .hideSoftInputFromWindow(mainLayout.getWindowToken(), 0);
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Hide your button this way
    }
```

Comment: also how to hide button simultaneously when click back button of device/phone? :((

Comment: which is the problem you facing ??

Comment: when click back button of device, hide keyboard but still button is showed

Comment: impossible becoz same method i can use in my code please check your button id is same as like you `xml`